# Is there a lag function in Spotfire that can fetch previous value for hour column?

Tags: spotfire

My data looks like this

```
Date       Hour
8/8/2017   23
8/9/2017   00
8/9/2017   01
8/9/2017   02
8/9/2017   03
8/9/2017   04
8/9/2017   05
8/9/2017   06
8/9/2017   07
8/9/2017   08
8/9/2017   09
8/9/2017   10
8/9/2017   11
8/9/2017   12
8/9/2017   13
8/9/2017   14
8/9/2017   15
8/9/2017   16
8/9/2017   17
8/9/2017   18
8/9/2017   19
8/9/2017   20
8/9/2017   21
8/9/2017   22
8/9/2017   23
```

I want to use a similar logic to a lag function here to get a previous hour column.
I have tried the following Spotfire expression for a calculated column:

```
First([Hour]) OVER Intersect([Date],Previous([Hour]))
```

However this is not giving me a previous value for hour 00, following is the result

```
Date       Hour  PrevHour
8/8/2017   23    22
8/9/2017   00    
8/9/2017   01    00
8/9/2017   02    01
8/9/2017   03    02   
8/9/2017   04    03
8/9/2017   05    04
......
```

How can I make the previous hour of 00 to be 23 of previous date?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to solve this, I'm posting it here incase anyone faces the same problem someday.

1. Sort data by Date then Hour columns
2. Create new ID calculated column in Spotfire with custom expression = RowId()
3. Create PrevHour calculated column using the following custom expression = First([Hour]) OVER Previous([ID])

This solved my problem.